# How to fix bind error using Java Networking and MAMP

Tags: java, networking, mamp

## Client Side

I am using this on my pc. I am using MAMP and it is installed and everything seems fine but.

```
package com.data.jdbc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClientDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        Socket s  = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8888);

        Scanner is = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());  //receive data from server

        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scan.next();
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        p.println(name);
        String temp=is.next();


        System.out.println(temp);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

## Server Side

I am using this on my pc , MAMP is installed and everything seems fine but.

```
   package com.data.jdbc;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ServerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ServerSocket sc1 = new ServerSocket(8888);
        Socket s11 = sc1.accept();
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(s11.getInputStream());
        String name1 = scan1.next();
        String temp1= name1 + "Poudel";

        PrintStream p1 = new PrintStream(s11.getOutputStream());

        p1.println(temp1);

    }
}
```

## Error

I am getting a bind error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at com.data.jdbc.ServerDemo.main(ServerDemo.java:18)
```

**What might be the cause of above problem?**

Comment: The port 8888 is already being used by another process. Use a different port.

Comment: The server port 8888 is already used by another program. On windows you can use "netstat -ano" to get the list of sockets including the process ID. You need to check the port 8888 and which process uses this port.

Comment: get TCPView from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview and see what is using 8888. then you have to close that application or change the port you are using.

Comment: It's quite possible that 8888 is used by another instance of your program that is still running

Comment: Thanks raviiii1 and Konrad . Problem is solved